# Fade TDirectShow Player (Inno Media Player) volume gradually in Inno Setup

Tags: media-player, inno-setup, pascalscript

I wrote following code to fade out the Video Playback volume as descending gradually when the installer finishes installing my program.

```pascal
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
var
   X: Integer;
begin
  ... 
  if CurPageID = wpFinished then
  begin
    VideoHandler.Release;
    VideoHandler.Close;
    DSSetVolume(-0);
    X := 0;
    repeat
      DSSetVolume(X);
      Log(IntToStr(X));
      X = X - 1;
    until X = -10000;
    DSStopMediaPlay;
  ...
  end;
  ...
end;
```

*Above code outputs the X value as I expecting to reduce volume gradually and I can see it like `-1 , -2 ... -10000` in the log well. But when this repeat process starts,*

- *`WizardForm` appears normally, but nothing is displaying in its `wpFinished` Page. Only an empty form is displaying. There is nothing is drawn in the form except `WizardForm.Caption`. It behaves like freezing until the repeat process (loop) finishes.*
- *Volume never reduces normally or to a gradual descending order.*
- *After the loop finishes and Log outputs `-10000`, `WizardForm` displays normally and page also showing normally. Volume stops suddenly because I set to `DSStopMediaPlay`.*

How can I do the above process (gradual reduction of video playback sound) correctly without any freezing or exception?

**UPDATE**

*Following Code can give best results when the User's System Sound has been set to `20%` in Sound Control Panel in Windows.*

```pascal
procedure VolumeFadeTimerProc(HandleW, msg, idEvent, TimeSys: LongWord);
begin
  MPEGVideoVolume := MPEGVideoVolume - 15;
  if MPEGVideoVolume < -4000 then
  begin
    DSStopMediaPlay;
    KillTimer( 0, TimerID);
    KillTimer( 0, VolumeFadeTimer);
    Log('Volume Fade Timer has been reset.');
  end
    else
  begin
    Log('MPEG Video Volume has been set to: ' + IntToStr(MPEGVideoVolume));
    DSSetVolume(MPEGVideoVolume);
  end;
end;
```

Volume Reducing Amount is 15

Maximum Reducing Volume Amount is -4000

*Following Code can give best results when the User's System Sound has been set to `100%` in Sound Control Panel in Windows.*

```pascal
procedure VolumeFadeTimerProc(HandleW, msg, idEvent, TimeSys: LongWord);
begin
  MPEGVideoVolume := MPEGVideoVolume - 35;
  if MPEGVideoVolume < -10000 then
  begin
    DSStopMediaPlay;
    KillTimer( 0, TimerID);
    KillTimer( 0, VolumeFadeTimer);
    Log('Volume Fade Timer has been reset.');
  end
    else
  begin
    Log('MPEG Video Volume has been set to: ' + IntToStr(MPEGVideoVolume));
    DSSetVolume(MPEGVideoVolume);
  end;
end;
```

Volume Reducing Amount is 35

Maximum Reducing Volume Amount is -10000

Do I need to automatically change Volume Reducing Amount and Maximum Reducing Volume according to the Amount of user's System Sound set to?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you stop the window message pump in your loop. What freezes the window and probably also prevents the volume fade out.

You have to use a timer to fade out the volume without freezing the message pump.

```pascal
[Code]

function SetTimer(
  hWnd: longword; nIDEvent, uElapse: LongWord; lpTimerFunc: LongWord): LongWord;
  external 'SetTimer@user32.dll stdcall';

var
  Volume: Integer;
  VolumeFadeTimer: LongWord;

procedure VolumeFadeTimerProc(
  H: LongWord; Msg: LongWord; IdEvent: LongWord; Time: LongWord);
begin
  { Fade by -1000 every 100 ms }
  Volume := Volume - 1000;
  if Volume <= -10000 then
  begin
    DSStopMediaPlay;
    KillTimer(0, VolumeFadeTimer);
  end
    else
  begin
    DSSetVolume(Volume);
  end;
end;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  if CurPageID = wpFinished then
  begin
     VideoHandler.Release;
     VideoHandler.Close;

     Volume := 0;
     { call VolumeFadeCallback every 100 ms }
     VolumeFadeTimer := SetTimer(0, 0, 100, CreateCallback(@VolumeFadeTimerProc));
     DSSetVolume(Volume);
  end;
end;
```

*For [`CreateCallback` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_createcallback), you need Inno Setup 6. If you are stuck with Inno Setup 5, you can use `WrapCallback` function from [InnoTools InnoCallback](http://www.sherlocksoftware.org/page.php?id=54) library.*